# Get a flux desniry gradient on the mollview map using healpix

Tags: python, flux, colorbar, astropy, healpy

Mollview:Mapping the flux density map(colors visible on the mollview map based on their magnitude)

I have to create a flux weighted map and present the data in mollview map, plotting the flux desnity as a fucntion of their magnitude, i.e the points on the mollview map show a gradient of the flux densities.

my code is:

```
type hzero_point_flux = {'w1': 3.23e-6, 'w2': 1.93e-6}
flux_w1 = catwise_data[1].data['w1']
flux_w2 = catwise_data[1].data['w2']
lux_density_w1 = zero_point_flux['w1'] * 10 ** (-0.4 * flux_w1)
flux_density_w2 = zero_point_flux['w2'] * 10 ** (-0.4 * flux_w2)
cmap=cm.get_cmap('magma')
flux_map1 = scattomap(l,b, flux_density_w1, nside)
hp.mollview(flux_map1, min=8.106317896967679e-13, max=7.641015396188297e-10, unit='Jy',cmap=cmap)
flux_map2 = scattomap(l,b, flux_density_w2, nside)
hp.mollview(flux_map2, min=0.001, max=0.0, unit='Jy')ere
plt.show()
```

My flux density values are different (attaching first ten values for reference purpose):

```
Index:0,Flux Column :w1,Flux Value:15.993808462787793,Flux Density:1.2932400247491991e-12
Index:0,Flux Column :w2,Flux Value:15.00453897519186,Flux Density:1.9219483790848216e-12
Index:1,Flux Column :w1,Flux Value:16.235973266815765,Flux Density:1.0346970612514506e-12
Index:1,Flux Column :w2,Flux Value:15.006648844543845,Flux Density:1.9182171573632337e-12
Index:2,Flux Column :w1,Flux Value:15.97998871052079,Flux Density:1.309806188785171e-12
Index:2,Flux Column :w2,Flux Value:14.796992473680525,Flux Density:2.326806774278305e-12
Index:3,Flux Column :w1,Flux Value:16.484363331750036,Flux Density:8.231086953799009e-13
Index:3,Flux Column :w2,Flux Value:15.576908887833357,Flux Density:1.134471927851256e-12
Index:4,Flux Column :w1,Flux Value:16.113238577538354,Flux Density:1.1585294852544302e-12
Index:4,Flux Column :w2,Flux Value:14.800825718358904,Flux Density:2.3186063538733967e-12
```

The resulting moll view map looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZhkv.png)

I want to show the distribution of flux across the map, but instead of forming a gradient like pattern it is showing that every flux density is mapped to the lowest magnitude value.
Any help is appreciated.Thank you